# Merge Compound Path with its Stroke in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient

I have a vector that is in Compound Path Format. It also has a stroke.
I Would like to apply a Gradient to it, but as applying two gradients (one for the color itself and one for stroke) creates a buggy effect, I would like to merge the path with its stroke to create a new shape and then apply the gradient to it.

I cannot find a solution to do so. `Expand Appearance` is greyed out and `Outline Stroke` creates two Compound paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

1. Convert the shape to two compound paths using `Path > Outline Stroke`
2. Selecting both paths and creating a new shape with `Compound Path > Make`
   (Step 2 worked for me in one shape but is creating unexpected results in others)